# Как исправить ошибку в консоли Chome: chrome.loadTimes() is deprecated?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension, google-console

Возникает ошибка в консоли: Deprecation] chrome.loadTimes() is deprecated, instead use standardized API: nextHopProtocol in Navigation Timing 2.

```
// send spdy info for current page
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  spdy: loadTimes.wasFetchedViaSpdy,
  info: loadTimes.npnNegotiatedProtocol || loadTimes.connectionInfo
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (res, sender, sendResponse) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    spdy: loadTimes.wasFetchedViaSpdy,
    info: loadTimes.npnNegotiatedProtocol || loadTimes.connectionInfo
  });
});
```

Нашла следущее https://github.com/justjavac/ChromeSnifferPlus/iss... и https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/12/... НО ни один из вариантов не помог в решении ошибки. Помогите пожалуйста может кто сталкивался. У меня Chrome v 90.0.4430.212

Comment: nörbörnën, ошибка все равно есть

Comment: если вы заменили все применения loadTimes на функции, предложенные в chrome-loadtimes-deprecated, то ошибка должна быть другой. если ошибка всё ещё про loadTimes - вы не всё заменили. вообще, тяжело советовать что-либо в теме, связанно с расширениями браузера так как для повторения вашего кейса нужно написать само расширение. так что выкладывайте ссылку на репу или весь код

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, код вашего вопроса - это код браузерного расширения [chrome-spdy-indicator](https://github.com/rauchg/chrome-spdy-indicator).

https://github.com/rauchg/chrome-spdy-indicator/blob/master/content.js

```
var loadTimes = window.chrome.loadTimes();
// send spdy info for current page
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  spdy: loadTimes.wasFetchedViaSpdy,
  info: loadTimes.npnNegotiatedProtocol || loadTimes.connectionInfo
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (res, sender, sendResponse) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    spdy: loadTimes.wasFetchedViaSpdy,
    info: loadTimes.npnNegotiatedProtocol || loadTimes.connectionInfo
  });
});
```

Как вы уже сами поняли, ошибка

> Deprecation] chrome.loadTimes() is deprecated, instead use
> standardized API: nextHopProtocol in Navigation Timing 2

означает, что api `loadTimes` устарело и ему на смену пришло другое, [`Navigation Timing 2`](https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing-2/).

Гугл опубликовал подробнейшее руководство о том какими вызовами нового api можно заменить атрибуты `loadTimes` - [Chrome 64 to deprecate the chrome.loadTimes() API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/12/chrome-loadtimes-deprecated), например:

***wasFetchedViaSpdy***

```
function wasFetchedViaSpdy() {
 // SPDY is deprecated in favor of HTTP/2, but this implementation returns
 // true for HTTP/2 or HTTP2+QUIC/39 as well.
 if (window.PerformanceNavigationTiming) {
   const ntEntry = performance.getEntriesByType('navigation')[0];
   return ['h2', 'hq'].includes(ntEntry.nextHopProtocol);
  }
}
```

Ответ на ваш вопрос: берёшь `loadTimes.wasFetchedViaSpdy`, берёшь рекомендацию из статьи и заменяешь в коде.

Но можно не делать даже этого! В репозитории chrome-spdy-indicator есть [2 pull request](https://github.com/rauchg/chrome-spdy-indicator/pulls), которые переводят расширение на api `Navigation Timing 2`.

Берите любой, пользуйтесь.

Вот, [pull request](https://github.com/rauchg/chrome-spdy-indicator/pull/41/commits/0df069618d6e548803e511f4d35a381b374742bd), предложенный [Jeffrey Goh](https://github.com/jeffgoh):

```
function connectionInfo() {
  if (window.PerformanceNavigationTiming) {
    const ntEntry = performance.getEntriesByType('navigation')[0];
    return ntEntry.nextHopProtocol;
  }
}
function wasFetchedViaSpdy() {
  // SPDY is deprecated in favor of HTTP/2, but this implementation returns
  // true for HTTP/2 or HTTP2+QUIC/39 as well.
  if (window.PerformanceNavigationTiming) {
    const ntEntry = performance.getEntriesByType('navigation')[0];
    return ['h2', 'hq'].includes(ntEntry.nextHopProtocol);
  }
}
function npnNegotiatedProtocol() {
  // NPN is deprecated in favor of ALPN, but this implementation returns the
  // HTTP/2 or HTTP2+QUIC/39 requests negotiated via ALPN.
  if (window.PerformanceNavigationTiming) {
    const ntEntry = performance.getEntriesByType('navigation')[0];
    return ['h2', 'hq'].includes(ntEntry.nextHopProtocol) ?
        ntEntry.nextHopProtocol : 'unknown';
  }
}
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  spdy: wasFetchedViaSpdy(),
  info: npnNegotiatedProtocol() || connectionInfo()
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (res, sender, sendResponse) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    spdy: wasFetchedViaSpdy(),
    info: npnNegotiatedProtocol() || connectionInfo()
  });
});
```

---

p.s. не знаю зачем вам `spdy` в 2021 году, он ведь из 2011—2012...